# Firebug is too heavy

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firebug

When I work for a long time with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), it makes the browser too heavy, is there a way to clear cache or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is naturally [memory intensive](http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+memory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and demonstrates a bit of a leaky symptom most of the time. I've had a beta build (4.0) seem to stabilize around 400MB, but FF 3.6 will grow to double that easily. That is most likely the issue, not Firebug.

Though it could be Firebug's console (if that's open), net tab (if it's persisting) or anything else. I would try to measure memory consumption with Firebug on (over a period of a day) and off (over the same period).

Comment: Actually, Firefox's memory footprint is smaller than that of Safari and Opera, and MUCH smaller than that of Chrome. http://dotnetperls.com/chrome-memory

Comment: @phenry: That's Firefox with no customizations. Who doesn't add something to the browser? I can confirm memory usage exceeding 800MB in FF while the same browsing in Chrome yields less then 300MB usage.

Comment: Why buy RAM you're not going to use?  Unused memory is wasted memory.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try Developer Tools from Google Chrome, which is way lighter and faster than Firefox and has very similar features to Firebug (You can open them pressing control+shift+i)